# Launch Chrome from Android app but point to local content

Tags: android, google-chrome

So, from my app I can launch Chrome and get it to load a page using the `http://` using the code below.

My problem is that when I try and load content that is stored locally on the device. i.e. `file:///`, I get the error further down.

Any ideas on how to work around this?

**Code:**

```
String urlString="file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/primer.html";
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlString));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
startActivity(intent);
```

**Error:**

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/cuescript_primer.html
>   flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.android.chrome }

Comment: You're certainly welcome to add a MIME type to the `Intent`, but there's no requirement that Chrome support loading local files. This is one of the problems with hard-coding packages. The user might have another Web browser that could load local HTML. Or, the user might not want to use Chrome.

Comment: Hi Mark, actually the requirements are very specific. It's for an embedded device where Chrome is required to use WebRTC. Any ideas. I'm a subscriber of yours btw :)

Comment: Again, try `setType("text/html")`. Otherwise, you're out of luck for Chrome loading local files.

Comment: Damn, part of my overall solution is to use NodeJS. I guess i'll have to go down the localhost root. That should work, right?

Comment: Chrome should be able to talk to `localhost`. So can any other app on the device.